# how can i work with a pointer of pointers in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

i have a problem with C programming again. i have a function that basically has an array of structure elements as param and now i want to print a list of all of these elements in the array. but i don't get the syntax to do so.

ANLAGE is a struct with some float and int values and some char-arrays inside

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned int InventarNr;
    char Anlagenbez[15];
    char Standort[15];
    float Basiswert; /* in EUR */
    unsigned int Nutzdauer; /* in Jahren */
    unsigned int AnschJahr;
} ANLAGE;
```

the anlage_arr gets initialized like this:

```
ANLAGE *anlage_arr;
anlage_arr = malloc(sizeof(ANLAGE));
```

my function now looks like this:

```
int erstelle_anlagenliste(ANLAGE *anlage_arr, size_t size) {


    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%-15d%-20s%-20s%.1f%-15d%-15d%\n", 
                 anlage_arr[i].InventarNr,anlage_arr[i].Anlagenbez,
                 anlage_arr[i].Standort, anlage_arr[i].Basiswert, 
                 anlage_arr[i].Basiswert, anlage_arr[i].AnschJahr);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

and then i call the function like this:

```
erstelle_anlagenliste(&anlage_arr, size);
```

when i do so, i just get some random values, which are - i guess- the adresses of the values. but can anyone help me how i can get to the real values of the elements in the array?

thank you in advance!

Comment: OK, and we're supposed to answer this question without knowing what `ANLAGE` is or how `anlage_arr` is initialized prior to function `erstelle_anlagenliste` being called???

Comment: also, @barakmanos are we supposed to do horizontal scroll? Just askin' . :P

Comment: Please show an [mcve]

Comment: EDIT your question,and put the code in there, not in comments, please.  Hard to read.

Comment: **show the struct**

Comment: What is `size`?  It better be one because you only allocated one.  Also your `%-15d` should be `%-15u` due to unsigned int declarations.

Answer (score 1):

In this call

```
erstelle_anlagenliste(&anlage_arr, size);
```

the type of the first argument is `ANLAGE **` because the variable `anlage_arr` is declared like

```
ANLAGE *anlage_arr;
```

However the function expects that the first argument will have type `ANLAGE *`

```
int erstelle_anlagenliste(ANLAGE *anlage_arr, size_t size) {
```

Thus call the function like

```
erstelle_anlagenliste( anlage_arr, size);
                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also take into account that if you want to deal with an array with more than one element then instead of this statement

```
anlage_arr = malloc(sizeof(ANLAGE));
```

write something like

```
anlage_arr = malloc( size * sizeof(ANLAGE));
```